# ID selector isn't working in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this `html` code sample. When I write an `internal css` as follows it works fine. But when I implement it with a `ID selector` it won't.

The problem is picture size is more than it should be.

Here's the code without `ID selector`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Omicron.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="Header.png" alt="Header not Found" style="width:100%;min-width:10px;height:auto;position:relative;top:50px;">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

---

and here's the code with `ID selector` and here's its preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Omicron.com</title>
<style>
#headerImage{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerImage">
        <img src="Header.png" alt="Header not Found">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me  what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to change `#headerImage` to `#headerImage img`

Comment: @AnilM or simply don't put the ID in the `div`, and put it in the `img` instead, like so: `<img id="headerImage" src...`.  The thing is, the styles you're using don't automatically go to all of the element's children, so that's why it's not working at the moment.

Comment: @marcellothearcane: Than won't work :(

Comment: @user7980830 why not? what's not working? you can put IDs in images...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `div` with `id="headerImage"` is the `#headerImage` element. In the first example, you applied styles to the `img`. So in the second example, you're applying styles to the div. To apply styles to the `img` inside of `#headerImage` use `#headerImage img` as your selector.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Omicron.com</title>
<style>
#headerImage img {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="headerImage">
        <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="Header not Found">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the image, not its parent div.

```
#headerImage img{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
}
```